# How to prepare a mysql-query to loop in smarty section?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, smarty2

I am trying to prepare an array to use it in a Smarty {section} loop.

I developed a simple PHP script that is giving me exactly the results I want:

```
$userlist = mysql_query("SELECT user_username FROM table_users");

while($name = mysql_fetch_assoc($userlist)){
 echo $name['user_username'].", ";
}
```

Now instead of "echo" the results in php, I want to move the while-part into the tpl file, I've already created

```
$smarty->assign('users', $users);
$smarty->display('userlist.tpl');
```

Now in the .tpl file, I have

```
{section name="userlist" loop="$users"} 
name: {$users[userlist].user_username} <br /> 
{/section}
```

Now I'd like to know, how I need to prepare my $users array to assign it for the smarty loop section. I've tried a lot, but can't get it working when the array comes from the MySQL database, ...

Someone can help please?
Best regards.

Comment: Perhaps a loo around the section in PHP. It will get merged.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{foreach $users as $user}
name: {$user.user_username} <br /> 
{/foreach}
```

Anyway, as @John Conde said, MySQL_ functions are deprecated